# Android Q saved Uris valid on a new phone?

Tags: android, uri

Hi this is maybe more a question than a problem !?

Let´s assume i have Android Q installed.

OK for example i have a notes app and within a note an image slider is showing images from saved image uris in the database.

All images are saved in MediaStore under /Pictures/Mypictures for example.

The user is now making a backup of the database with all links saved. Also all images in the folder are automatically backed up to a cloud or wathever.

So what will happen if a user will now install the notes app on a new phone and also is restoring the database and the image folder back to the new phone ?

In my opinion "all" saved uris are not valid anymore because if a user makes a restore of the images folder then every "old" uri will become a new media link ? So none of the old links saved in the database will work anymore ?

Maybe i am completely wrong with this but if not is there any way to get the "new" valid uris from the new phone ?

Before it was very easy with getting the filepath from the saved image.

Comment: What exactly is stored in the db, and what backup method are they using?  There's a lot of backup apps out there.  I don't think this is answerable as is.

Comment: Only the  media uri for the image is saved into a sqlite database for example ! But as i mentioned the question is if the old media uri (saved in database) is still valid on a new phone if the user is restoring the image folder. And if the old uri is not valid anymore the question would be if there any possibility to get the new uri from the image on the new phone

Comment: FOr question 1, it would depend on the backup method.  For question 2, no.  After the restore is done, it wouldn't have any way to know the old value to get you the new one.